# Change the font type dynamically in c#.net using windows app

Tags: c#, fonts

I have two radio buttons: `Marathi` and `English`.

On the checked event of either I want to change the font of the text box.

I tried the following code, but it's not working:

```
txtPublisherName.font.fontfamily.equals("Elephant")
```

Comment: Please post *valid* code that has been tried. That code snippet likely does not even compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Equals` is a comparison. It just returns a bool, and does not set the value.

You'll need to create a new Font object for the font you want (e.g. `Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 20);` from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/164w6x6z.aspx)) and do `txtPublisherName.Font = newFont`

Answer (score 0):

By doing so you are checking whether txtPublisherName textbox current font is "Elephant" or not?

You can try this way

```
 textBox1.Font = new Font("Calibre", 20);
```